# How do I make two machine with elasticsearch installed on both of them, interact with each other in amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I am new to Amazon AWS. I have two machines in AWS EC2 with elasticsearch installed on both of them. I want both machines to be a part of a single Cluster in elasticsearch. How do I make both of them interact with each other in amazon AWS. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

check out [EC2 discovery](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws) which is similar to multicast (default zen discovery module)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multicasting to discover other hosts. On AWS you require the EC2 discovery plugin that Prabin Meitei mentioned in his answer. However, I typically recommend Unicast discovery and using domains with A records to keep track of your hosts. You can set `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [“host1″,”host2″]` to point elasticsearch to specific hosts. You should create domains(or subdomains) and make an A record for the internal IP of that host, then include that same unicast config in each of your deployments of elasticsearch.

Lets say you want to scale, and you only have the first 3 hosts in your unicast config, and you have 5 hosts in your cluster and you want to add 1 making a total of 6. You can add another host and it will discover the other 3 services, and it will propagate itself to connect to the remain 2 hosts. Now even is the IP had changed for any of these hosts, the A record will always be pointing the proper IP. Therefore minimizing the need to reconfigure, and making it easier to create scalable deployments.

Of course you could use multicasting to accomplish something similar. Its not really a security issue if you're using AWS VPC, however I personally don't like to rely on service discovery where I can handle it myself in a way that I'm certain will continue working, and won't fail due to a simple bug in the third party module provided for AWS discovery. This also makes maintenance easier because you have more control over your cluster and can  easily rotate nodes out and not have to worry about reconfiguring anything.